# Class xyz contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods Laravel\Nova\Tool::menu

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, laravel-nova

Am working on an app using Laravel Nova and wanted to implement a calendar from https://github.com/czemu/nova-calendar-tool.

I followed all instructions but have received the following error:

```
Class Czemu\NovaCalendarTool\NovaCalendarTool contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Laravel\Nova\Tool:: menu)
```

Here's my code throwing me the above error.

```
<?php


namespace Czemu\NovaCalendarTool;


use Laravel\Nova\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Tool;


class NovaCalendarTool extends Tool

{

    /**

     * Perform any tasks that need to happen when the tool is booted.

     *

     * @return void

     */

    public function boot()

    {

        Nova::script('nova-calendar-tool', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/tool.js');

        Nova::style('nova-calendar-tool', __DIR__.'/../dist/css/tool.css');

    }


    /**

     * Build the view that renders the navigation links for the tool.

     *

     * @return \Illuminate\View\View

     */

    public function renderNavigation()

    {

        return view('nova-calendar-tool::navigation');

    }

}
```

To be honest, this is the first time encountering such an error and have no idea what to do (coding noob). Just wanted my calendar to show up on my Nova resources.

Comment: Did you follow the installation? https://github.com/czemu/nova-calendar-tool#installation

Comment: Yes. Down to the "t."

Answer (score 1):

Nova 4 doesn't support that package, its outdated.

Check https://novapackages.com/?tag=all&search=Calendar+Tool to make sure if a package is tagged under nova 3 or nova 4

There is an alternative package: https://github.com/wdelfuego/nova-calendar

Comment: I figured that it was probably outdated. The repository was last updated last year. Checking out the alternative package. Thank you. Let me look into implementing it.